# .Net Core dependency injection: Get implementationtype(s) for servicetype (interface)

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

Is it possible to get the type of the registered implementation for a servicetype?

For example:
In my `Startup.ConfigureServices` I register an service like this (nothing special):

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  //...
  services.AddTransient<IBaseRepository, BaseRepository>();
  //...
}
```

`IBaseRepository` is the servicetype and `BaseRepository` the concrete implementation.

**Question**

Is there a way to get the registered **type** (not the instance) of the service interface?
In my example I would like to ask for `IBaseRepository` and get the type `BaseRepository`.

Edit on 10.02.2021 13:13 UTC: The following information is not part of the question and misleading.
<s>**Some more Background to my question**</s>

<s>At some later point I need an instance of this service and want to create it using
[ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.activatorutilities.createinstance?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0), because I need to pass value in the constuctor which is only known at runtime.
Here I need to pass the concrete type for the class I want to get a new instance.
It would be nice If I could pass the interface-type into my method, determine which class is registered for this interface and create a new instance.</s>

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Based on the backstory, the question in its current state is also incomplete and therefore unclear. Read [ask] and then edit the question to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that can be used to reproduce the problem, allowing a better understanding of what is actually being asked.

Comment: If you have the `IServiceCollection` (*not* the built `IServiceProvider`) you can operate on it with LINQ methods and find the registrations (plural!) where `descriptor.ServiceType==X` and select `descriptor.ImplementationType` though if any are registered with a factory or pre-made instance you'd have issues. But I still don't know *why* you'd want this

Comment: @pinkfloydx33: Thanks. That's what I was looking for. I spent hours trying and searching for a way to get the information out of the build `IServiceProvider`. 
And thanks for the hint with the factory. Helps me have an eye on it.

@Nkosi: My question was just: _Is it possible to get the type of the registered implementation for a servicetype?_. Do you think it would be clearer if I didn't add the part "Some more Background to my question"?

Comment: @BooFar yes the background added additional details that broadened the question to a point that diluted what you were actually looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still not completely clear why you need this, but... An `IServiceCollection` (*not* the built `IServiceProvider`) is just a collection of [`ServiceDescriptor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicedescriptor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) objects. All the extension methods that you use to configure your DI are essentially adding one or more descriptors to the collection.

Because it implements `IList<ServiceDescriptor>` (and thus `IEnumerable<ServiceDescriptor>`) you can perform LINQ operations against it to find a particular descriptor. There are four properties of note on a `ServiceDescriptor` that describe the service and its implementation.

- `ServiceType` - **Required**; the `Type` that will be requested from DI. Typically but not always an interface
- `ImplementationType` - *Optional*; the concrete `Type` that was registered
- `ImplementationInstance` - *Optional*; a singleton instance (static type `object`)
- `ImplementationFactory` - *Optional*; a `Func<IServiceProvider, object>` used as a factory method

Of the three optional properties, one (and only one)  will/must be specified. The fifth property, `Lifetime` describes, well, the lifetime (Singleton, Scoped, Transient).

If you want to find the concrete type**s** associated with a specific service type, you can use the following extension methods:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<Type> GetImplementationTypes<TService>(this IServiceCollection services) 
    where TService: class 
{
    if (services is null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));

    return services
        .Where(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(TService) && d.ImplementationType != null)
        .Select(d => d.ImplementationType);
}
// or alternatively
public static IEnumerable<Type> GetImplementationTypes(this IServiceCollection services, Type serviceType) 
{
    if (services is null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));

    if (serviceType is null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceType));

    return services
        .Where(d => d.ServiceType == serviceType && d.ImplementationType != null)
        .Select(d => d.ImplementationType);
}
```

Which you can then use:

```cs
IServiceCollection services =... 
var typeList = services.GetImplementationTypes<IBaseRepository>().ToList();
```

Note that this returns an `IEnumerable<Type>` as you can have multiple registrations for a single Service Type. It will also only return those that have been registered with a type, and not those that use a factory or a singleton instance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to use ActivatorUtilities for your scenario:

Check this code from [net core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0) about `GetRequiredService`, as I think it will solve your problem.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

        using (var serviceScope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;

            try
            {
                var myDependency = services.GetRequiredService<IMyDependency>();
                myDependency.WriteMessage("Call services from main");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred.");
            }
        }

        host.Run();
    }
```

Why is this preferred:

1. You are not adding instantiating logic anywhere outside the DI container, so no side effects there
2. In your case you added a `Transient` scoped service, so it should be ok. If that where a singleton, then it would be a bad practice to create a new singleton by the activator, as you would violate the original author's intent with unknown side effects (ok, they could be known but you get my point).

Comment: Hi Athanasios, thanks for your anwer. But how would `GetRequiredService` help to pass a parameter to the constuctor of the service, which is not registered in the DI container?

Comment: You will pass the parameter and use the GetRequiredService inside the class. Or is it something I misunderstood?

Comment: Sorry, I learned that my question was not clear. There was no  question how to use `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance`. The question was about how to get the information which imlementations are registered for a servicetype.